# How does one subset pandas dataframe dates on monthly endpoints?

Tags: python, pandas, date, time-series, endpoint

I am sure this is a really simple problem, so I appreciate your help and patience as I am quite new to python programming. I have a simple time series dataframe with a daily date index and value column. I want to subset this dataframe on monthly endpoints, e.g. 31st Jan, 28th Feb, 31st Mar, etc. However, I am not sure how to do this.

I am familiar with an equivalent function in R with the xts package:

```r
mends_xts <- my_xts[endpoints(my_xts, on = 'months')]
```

However, I am not familiar with the python function and I am struggling to find the equivalent online.

Here is my example pandas time series dataframe:

```py
idx = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=100, freq='D')
ts = pd.Series(range(len(idx)), index=idx)
ts_sub = ts[....] # I am really unsure what to put in this part to subset the dates
```

I expect the output to look like:

2018-01-31     30

2018-02-28     58

2018-03-31     89

Thanks again for the help in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Month ends can be obtained by the `M` frequency string:

```
idx1 = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=3, freq='M')
ts_sub = ts[ts=idx1]
```

Output:

```
2018-01-31    30
2018-02-28    58
2018-03-31    89
```

Comment: Thanks, but this assumes that the dates in the idx1 are in the original ts, which, admittedly, is how I presented my question.

However, suppose that in the time series there is a month that ends on the 30th but the data in the time series for that month only goes up to the 28th, then this method would not return last date in the month for the specific time series. Do you know how one can get the month endpoints from the time series itself?

Comment: IIUC you're looking for what Serge Ballesta wrote in the second part of his answer below: `idx1 = pd.date_range(ts.index.min(), ts.index.max(), freq='M')`

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `resample`:

```
ts_sub = ts.resample('M')
```

But you will get a value even for an incomplete month

```
2018-01-31    30
2018-02-28    58
2018-03-31    89
2018-04-30    99
Freq: M, dtype: int64
```

If you do not want that, you can extract the relevant indexes:

```
ts_sub = ts.loc[pd.date_range(ts.index.min(), ts.index.max(), freq='M')]
```